# Returning Route Parameter in a page in SLIM 3

Tags: slim, slim-3

i a, having a link which sends public to view timeline of a specific user by passing variable in route.

```
<a href="<?php echo $baseLocation ?>/bnb-details/<?php echo $row['username']?>" >View</a>
```

and my route is defined as:

```
$app->get('/bnb-details/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
include_once('bnb-details.php');
return $response; });
```

how can i pass the {name} args in the bnb-details.php ??

any kind of help would be appriciated.

Comment: What is the output of your script if you add `var_dump($args)` to your `bnb-details.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this :
you should pass parametere from args to variable

```
$app->get('/bnb-details/{name}', function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response, $args) {
    $name = $args['name'];
    include_once('bnb-details.php');
    return $response;
});
```

then use

```
echo $name;
```

in bnb-details.php

Comment: or its better to use controllers for this ;)